# C++ Pointer to Template Class With (virtual) Inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, callback

Currently I'm working on a GUI system, and I've made a GUIButton object which has this inheritance structure:

```
GUIObject
    |
GUIImage
    |
GUIButton
```

Where GUIObject is a base class with some virtual functions (render, update, etc).

Anyway, because of the way I want to handle callbacks for the GUI system, GUIButton is a template class, where `T` is the object that has a method that should be called back.

Here's the header file:

```
 #include "GUIImage.h"

template<class CallbackClass> 
class GUIButton : public GUIImage
{
public:

    // Constructor //
    GUIButton();

    // GUIObject Overides //

    bool update(const GUIUpdateInfo& updateInfo);
    void update();

    void render(const GUIRenderInfo& renderInfo);

    string getType();

    // Callback //

    void setCallback(void (CallbackClass::* callback)(), CallbackClass* instance);

    // Destructor //
    ~GUIButton();

private:

    void (CallbackClass::*  m_callback)();
    CallbackClass*          m_callTo; 
};
```

You can see that their is also the function setCallBack, which sets the method from the CallbackClass and the particular instance to be used.

Anyway, after all this, my code compiles fine but the moment I try to use the new class I get the following linking error:

```
    Undefined symbols:
  "GUIButton<GUIAppTest>::GUIButton()", referenced from:
      GUIAppTest::GUIAppTest()in GUIAppTest.o
      GUIAppTest::GUIAppTest()in GUIAppTest.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm working with Xcode as an IDE, so the error format might be slightly different then normal.

The code that uses the class is like so:

```
GUIButton<GUIAppTest>* newButton = new GUIButton<GUIAppTest>();

newButton->loadImage("Data/Sketch.png", 1);
newButton->setTextureCoordinates(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
newButton->setLocationCoordinates(0.0, 0.0, 84, 84);

newButton->setCallback(&GUIAppTest::onClick, this);

m_objects.push_back(newButton);
```

The problem is probably something very simple, but I've been stuck here for a while now so I thought I might as well get some help. The use of GUIButton actually occurs within the implementation of GUIAppTest - the class that is passed as a template to GUIButton - Would might this be the cause of my problem?

I'm certain that all my functions have been implemented as well, so the problem shouldn't lie there.

If anyone could give me some pointers, I'd much appreciate it!

Comment: Note that *virtual* inheritance is something different; please see e.g. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html.  And change your question title!

Comment: GUIObject has virtual functions... isn't that then virtual inheritance?

Comment: @Tomas Virtual functions imply late binding. This has nothing to do with virtual inheritance.

Comment: @Thomas: no, that's not virtual inheritance, refer to the given link, the explanation is very clear.

Comment: GUIObject has virtual functions which GUIButton uses, while my problem had naught to do with virtual inheritance I didn't know that and mentioned it in case that might have been the cause.

Comment: Am I missing something on the link? It seems like its talking about good object oriented programming practises in terms of virtual and multiple inheritance, it doesn't seem to actually have a definition for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define constructor

```
template<class CallbackClass>  
class GUIButton : public GUIImage 
{ 
public: 

    // Constructor // 
    GUIButton() : m_callTo(), m_callback() {} // <---- here
```

Comment: Is it necessary that the constructor must be defined in the classes first declaration?

Comment: yes, or out of calss but in the same h-file: `template<class CallbackClass> GUIButton<CallbackClass>::GUIButton() : m_callTo(), m_callback() {}`.

Comment: Actually `template<class CallbackClass> GUIButton<CallbackClass>::GUIButton() : m_callTo(), m_callback() {}`

Answer (score 0):

You error message says it all:

> Undefined symbols: "GUIButton::GUIButton()", referenced from: ...

You have declared, but not defined `GUIButton`'s constructor.

Comment: @Tomas Show us the definition (you can skip the body).

Comment: @Thomas: read my answer carefully! You have *declared*, but not *defined* it. There are two ways to define the constructor: in the class and outside it. Moreover, with template classes, your constructor must be defined *inline* (e.g. not in a `.cpp` file).

Comment: @Nim: no, strictly speaking, as my post says, he has **declared** the constructor. The **definition** is the implementation.

Comment: yeah, just got that from Alexey Malistov

Comment: @Andre, =) I've never really got to grips with define/declare/implement, I always assumed you "declare a variable", and "define and implement a function", prototype is the "definition" and then implementation is er well, the implementation... But I guess you could also say, declare the prototype and define the implementation.. don't you just love the English language...

Comment: @Nim: what's even more annoying is that some terminology changes across languages. The procedure/function/method terminology is another example. However, learning and using the proper terminology gets you bonus reputation points once in a while ;-)